# How to wait for promises in a for loop to complete before returning the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop

I have a for loop in which each iteration runs a promise and adds the index of the promise to the array if the promise is resolved, and in the end, I want to output the resulted array. However, the function keeps returning the array before completing all the promises in the for loop. As a result, I always get an empty returned array.

My code looks like this:

```
var str_list = [some strings];

let myFunction = () => {
    var array = [];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (str_list[i] fulfills some conditions) {
                resolve();
            } else {
                reject(
                    throw new Error())
            }
        }).then(() => {
            array.push(i);
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(i, err);
        });
    }
    return array;
}
```

Is there a good way to wait for the for loop to complete before returning the value?

Comment: Use `Promise.all()`.

Comment: Working on a response to your question, but please please please take some time to learn proper code formatting standards. It will save you and those around you many headaches!

Comment: lol sorry. Second day on javascript. Used to work with python mostly so please forgive all my terrible js formatting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var str_list = ["..."];

let myFunction = async () =>
{
    const promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            const condition = // ...
            resolve(condition ? str_list[i] : false);
        }));
    }

    return (await Promise.all(promises)).filter(f => f !== false);
}
```

Try this. Essentially, what it does is that it adds all of the Promises to an array, and then calls `Promise.all` on them, which executes them in parallel and waits for all of them to finish.

The results are then returned in order, those results being what was passed into the `resolve()` function in each `Promise`, and will be either `str_list[i]` or `false`. Then, the call to `filter()` removes all of the entries that are `false`.

If you care about being concise, then this can be greatly simplified:

```js
var str_list = ["..."];

let myFunction = async () =>
{
    const promises = str_list.map(async (value, index) => condition ? value : false);

    return (await Promise.all(promises)).filter(f => f !== false);
}
```

This code works the same way as the first snippet; it's just much shorter.

I made the method `async` because there is no way to return the results of a `Promise` without `await`ing it. If you don't want to use an `async` method, you can either return a `Promise`, which you can then wait on with `await` or `.then()`:

```js
var str_list = ["..."];

let myFunction = () => {
  const promises = [];
  for (i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const condition = // ...
        resolve(condition ? str_list[i] : false);
    }));
  }

  return Promise.all(promises).then(strs => strs.filter(f => f !== false));
}

// myFunction().then(results => ...)
```

Or you can use a callback:

```js
var str_list = ["..."];

let myFunction = (callback) =>
{
    const promises = [];
    for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        promises.push(new Promise((resolve, reject) =>
        {
            const condition = // ...
            resolve(condition ? str_list[i] : false);
        }));
    }

    return Promise.all(promises).then(results => callback(results.filter(f => f !== false));
}

// myFunction(results => ...);
```